# trace results in a locked warning, why?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I wanted to analyse the execution of my code using `trace`, and hence I entered

```
(trace oddp)
```

into the REPL. In contrast to what I expected I got an error message telling me:

```
** - Continuable Error
TRACE(ODDP): #<PACKAGE COMMON-LISP> is locked
If you continue (by typing 'continue'): Ignore the lock and proceed
```

What exactly does this mean, why does it happen, and is it safe to proceed by ignoring the lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRACE` works by redefining the function to something that prints the trace messages and then calls the original function. But you're not normally allowed to redefine built-in functions, so you get this error.